# Pass Variable and Value from One Card to Another Card Livecode

Tags: livecode

I have a livecode project with two cards in a mainstack.

- One card "Card1" has a text field  and a "submit" button.
- The other card "Card2" has a label.

I want the user to enter a text into the text field of "Card1". When the "submit" button is clicked, it jumps to another card which is "Card2" with the label text showing the content of the text field of "Card1"

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do

```
put cd fld "textField" into cd fld "otherField" of card "Card2"
```

to do that. If that doesn't work, you can instead do

```
put cd fld "textField" into theFieldText
go to card "Card2"
put theFieldText into cd fld "OtherField"
```

or alternately, you could use a global variable that the "Submit" button puts the field into, and an `openCard` handler on Card2 reads again and puts in the field. You can also use `lock screen` and `go back` if you don't want to go to Card2 yet to get back to the first card.

Comment: I would slightly modify Uli's excellent answer: LiveCode object addressing is slightly different from HyperCard's, upon which it is based. In LiveCode you don't need to refer to 'card field "textField"' or 'background field "textField"', for example. Simply refer to field "textField" or button "myButton".